# Merge three arrays of hashes in different way

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm new to Ruby and trying to build a meeting app. I have three arrays containing hashes :

- one containing my scheduled meetings with dates and therefore an empty array
  of people
- one containing the people invited per meeting
- and a last one containing the people who refused

This materializes as:

```
meetings = [
 {:id=>"1", :peoples=>[]}
 {:id=>"2", :peoples=>[]}
 {:id=>"3", :peoples=>[]}
]

invited_peoples = [
 {:id=>"1", :peoples=>['Tom', 'Henry', 'Georges', 'Nicolas']}
 {:id=>"2", :peoples=>['Arthur', 'Carl']}
]

absent_peoples = [
 {:id=>"1", :peoples=>['Henry', 'Georges']}
]
```

And I would like to have : meetings + invited_peoples - absent_peoples like

```
meetings_with_participants = [
 {:id=>"1", :peoples=>['Tom', 'Nicolas']}
 {:id=>"2", :peoples=>['Arthur', 'Carl']}
 {:id=>"3", :peoples=>[]}
]
```

I'm looking for a readable solution but I don't find anyone...

Sorry for my english and thank you in advance, 
Nicolas

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Define a method to find object by id

```
def find_by_id array_of_hash, id
  array_of_hash.find {|x| x[:id] == id} || {peoples: []}
end
```

#### Use map to turn a new array, inside map block just use your logic `meetings + invited_peoples - absent_peoples like`

```
result = meetings.map do |item|
  id = item[:id]
  {id: id, peoples: item[:peoples] + find_by_id(invited_peoples, id)[:peoples] - find_by_id(absent_peoples, id)[:peoples]}
end
```

#### Result:

```
=> [{:id=>"1", :peoples=>["Tom", "Nicolas"]}, {:id=>"2", :peoples=>["Arthur", "Carl"]}, {:id=>"3", :peoples=>[]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create a simple hash**

```
h = meetings.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:id]] = g[:peoples] }
  #=> {"1"=>[], "2"=>[], "3"=>[]}
```

**Add invitees**

```
invited_peoples.each { |g| h[g[:id]] += g[:peoples] }
```

Now

```
h #=> {"1"=>["Tom", "Henry", "Georges", "Nicolas"],
  #    "2"=>["Arthur", "Carl"], "3"=>[]}
```

**Remove declinees**

```
absent_peoples.each { |g| h[g[:id]] -= g[:peoples] }
```

Now

```
h #=> {"1"=>["Tom", "Nicolas"], "2"=>["Arthur", "Carl"],
  #    "3"=>[]}
```

**Convert the hash to an array of hashes**

```
h.map { |k,v| { :id=> k, :peoples=> v } }
  #=> [{:id=>"1", :peoples=>["Tom", "Nicolas"]},
  #    {:id=>"2", :peoples=>["Arthur", "Carl"]},
  #    {:id=>"3", :peoples=>[]}]
```

I initially created a hash and only after processing the invitees and decliners did I convert it to an array of hashes. Doing it that way sped `:id` lookups for adding and removing people. As a consequence, if `n = meetings.size`, these calculations have a computational complexity close to O(n), "close to" because hash key lookups have a computational complexity that is nearly O(1) (that is, the time needed to locate a key and its value is nearly constant, regardless of the size of the hash). By contrast, methods that search for a value of `:id` in `invited_peoples` and `absent_peoples`, for each element of `meetings`, have computational complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).